# Unable to build pandas from source: cl.exe failed with exit status 2

Tags: visual-studio, pandas, setuptools, cl

I've been trying to build pandas from source so I can verify some changes I have made, before submitting a pull request.

However, after having tried for more than 2 hours with different visual studio development tools variations, I was wondering if there's no better way to get a more precise error message to find out what the problem is.

I'm using windows 10, but I've also added the Windows8.1 SDK, python and anything else that looks remotely relevant in the Visual Studio 2017 installer, but the problem remains unsolved.. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -IC:\Users\dickr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\dickr\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\dickr\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpandas\_libs/index.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pandas\_libs/index.obj
index.c
c:\users\dickr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
c:\users\dickr\git\pandas\pandas\_libs\src\klib\khash.h(574): warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
pandas/_libs/src/klib\khash_python.h(66): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_hash_t' to 'khint_t', possible loss of data
pandas/_libs/src/klib\khash_python.h(72): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_hash_t' to 'khint_t', possible loss of data
pandas/_libs/src/klib\khash_python.h(77): warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
pandas\_libs/index.c(1219): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'pandas_datetimestruct'
pandas\_libs/index.c(1222): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
pandas\_libs/index.c(6470): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
pandas\_libs/index.c(19369): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
pandas\_libs/index.c(20841): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
pandas\_libs/index.c(22313): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
pandas\_libs/index.c(48803): error C2027: use of undefined type '__pyx_obj_6pandas_5_libs_6tslibs_10conversion__TSObject'
pandas\_libs/index.c(1217): note: see declaration of '__pyx_obj_6pandas_5_libs_6tslibs_10conversion__TSObject'
pandas\_libs/index.c(52568): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
pandas\_libs/index.c(52574): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: The first problem reported is a syntax error that looks like it's missing syntactical punctuation somewhere - are you sure you have a clean copy of the source?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Any diff would show in git

Comment: You're right, recloning the whole repo solved the problem. The error message changed to pointing that cython was missing from the venv. All working now.